# How to remove POS tags from a CSV file

Tags: python, regex

I am doing some Natural Language processing in which I have generated the following output:

```
connect^NN - appears^VBZ cant^JJ lose^JJ make^VBP pretty^JJ pro^JJ make^JJ compared^VBN made^VBD tracked^VBD navigate^JJ click^JJ kept^VBD trail^JJ downloaded^VBD
gps^NN - hope^VBP happy^JJ appears^VBZ entire^JJ reading^VBG good^VB start^VBP eg^JJ negative^JJ crashed^VBD happens^VBZ save^JJ expect^VBP certain^JJ drain^VBP
app^NN - nt^VB go^VBP see^VB relate^JJ pervious^JJ
```

I need to write a script to get rid of all the POS tags such as ^NN, ^VBZ, ^JJ, ^VBP and hence achieve the following output:

```
 connect - appears cant lose make pretty pro make compared made tracked navigate click kept trail downloaded
  app - nt go see relate pervious
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that every POS tags starts with the '^' characters and ends with the space character, you can use the following regex:

```
import re
re.sub('\^.*?\s', ' ', string)
```

[image]

Comment: True. That's great. Hadn't noticed.